# Yearly visits to UK

Tags: visas, uk

My husband and 2 children and I previously lived in the UK on a work visa.  We loved it and would like to return and visit for 5-6 months every year. We wont be working or using the NHS. We just love the culture and geography. Would this be possible or would we likely be denied entry at some point?

Comment: How can you know that you won't be needing the NHS? Somebody might hit you in the head. - Where do you come from? That might affect the answer.

Comment: @set2jet18 How old are your children? What about schooling?

Comment: There's a catchall rule that visitors must not effectively live in the UK by frequent or lengthy visits. Staying 5 to 6 months once will be fine. Trying to do it repeatedly could result in you being denied entry later.

Comment: I would also like to spend 5-6 months on holiday every year... But how will you live?

Comment: We have international medical insurance. We home school so we can live where we want.

Comment: And you make enough money in the remaining 6-7 months, that you can spend 5-6 months in the UK without an income?

Comment: @Henrik That’s an irrelevant personal question and none of your business. They have previously lived there so are not clueless.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen you may think so, but Immigration might well ask it anyway.

Comment: @CannonFodder Specifically, if you're spending six months a year in the UK, then you're living in the UK just as much as you're living in the place where you spend the other six months of the year.

Comment: @set2jet18 If you're involved in a life-threatening incident, you'll be taken to an NHS hospital and who pays for it will be dealt with later.

Comment: Thanks for the input. @HonoraryWorldCitizen, you are correct we do understand how it works and are not stupid. We would obviously have proof of income.

Comment: Please, no personal questions like "WOW HOW DID YOU GET SO MUCH MONEY".  Let us stay classy.

Comment: Many, many, people travel a HUGE fraction of the year, bumming around in hotels etc, but still have a literal home somewhere, and that's where they live.  (Oddly, this seems to apply either to successful people who have enough money to do that, or, younger "bumming around the world" types!!)

Comment: @Fattie Unless comments have been deleted, nobody has asked any such question.

Answer (score 4):

The UK does not place a formal limit on the number of visits or their cumulative duration. However they do have a rule that visitors (whether on Visas or Visa-free) must not try to live in the UK through frequent or successive visits. Spending nearly half your life in the UK is IMO getting dangerously close to living in the UK.

Unfortunately it is difficult to quantify the risks because the official statistics only talk in very broad brush terms and anecdotes mostly come from people who have had a problem, not from people who got in successfully.

Comment: Honestly, six months a year isn't dangerously close: it _is_ living in the UK. If you spend six months a year in the UK and six months in, say, Canada, you're living just as much in the UK are you are in Canada.

Comment: IMHO it is more likely than not that an entire family, including children of school age, arriving for a second 5-6 month long visit will experience a pretty challenging landing interview and may well not be allowed to enter or will have the intended length of stay curtailed.